how to animate in blender?
[starting and final form, dodecahedron
step one
create dodecahedron
step two
rotate all the faces of the dodecahedron 180 degrees along the axis that passes through the center of the solid and pair of opposite faces center
step three
move the faces to the center of the solid perpendicular to the axis from the center of each face to the center of the solid by a distance of .618033988H.... where H is the distance from the center of each face to the center of the solid....that is all ...thanks everyone in advance
